# Skip End of File when reading JSON

Tags: json, r

I have a json file which has several end of file lines.

I'm using rjson & jsonlite in the R language.

How can I skip or deal with these lines so I can read the whole file?

PS: the pattern contains quotations & curly brackets.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `n` argument of `readLines()` to read a limited number of lines. Reading the first ten lines:

```
con <- file('sample.json')
x <- readLines(con, n = 10)
close(con)
```

Or you could read all the lines in and exclude however many you want, e.g. I'm excluding the last ten here:

```
con <- file('sample.json')
all_lines <- readLines(con)
close(con)
x <- tail(all_lines, -10)
```

Now you can pass `x` to `jsonlite::fromJSON()`.

---

## Excluding Lines Based on Pattern

Once you have all your lines read in, you can easily exclude lines you don't want with `grepl()`. E.g. this will exclude all lines containing the string `'something'`.

```
x[!grepl('something', x)]
```

Comment: This doesn't solve it since the lines are sparsed throughout the file. Moreover, the file is 25,000 lines so I need an automated solution. Maybe gsub would work, but how do I replace remove the whole line if I only a part of it is the pattern?

Comment: @user10853 I've updated the answer to show you how to exclude lines based on some pattern.

Comment: The pattern contains quotations & curly brackets so it returns an "unexpected symbol" error.